# I don't understand why i have a problem with toString of Lombok

Tags: java, tostring, lombok

My question is about `@ToString` of Lombok.
I dont understand why i have this error:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractSet.hashCode(AbstractSet.java:120)
    at com.protypangel.market_selling.entity.market.shopping.ShoppingCart.hashCode(ShoppingCart.java:11)
    at com.protypangel.market_selling.entity.market.shopping.CartItem.hashCode(CartItem.java:9)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractSet.hashCode(AbstractSet.java:124)
    at com.protypangel.market_selling.entity.market.shopping.ShoppingCart.hashCode(ShoppingCart.java:11)
    at com.protypangel.market_selling.entity.market.shopping.CartItem.hashCode(CartItem.java:9)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractSet.hashCode(AbstractSet.java:124)
    at com.protypangel.market_selling.entity.market.shopping.ShoppingCart.hashCode(ShoppingCart.java:11)
    at com.protypangel.market_selling.entity.market.shopping.CartItem.hashCode(CartItem.java:9)
```

When I exclude the reading's property of `ShoppingCart` in `CartItem`.

That doesn't simply cancel the loop?

In my mind:

```
ShoppingCart => CartItem =x=> ShoppingCart (great)
ShoppingCart => CartItem => ShoppingCart => ... (bad)
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class ShoppingCart {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) private Long id;
    @ToString.Exclude @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) Client client;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "shoppingCart") Set<CartItem> items;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class CartItem {
    @Id private String id;
    @ToString.Exclude @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) ShoppingCart shoppingCart;
    private String productReference;
    @PrePersist void setId() {
        this.id = new StringBuilder(shoppingCart.getId().toString()).append("+").append(productReference).toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems the `hashCode` of `CartItem` also tries to call into `hashCode` of `ShoppingCart` which causes the exact problem you describe, except with `hashCode` instead of `toString`. I don't know the details of Lombok, but it seems you must exclude the `shoppingCart` property from the `equals`/`hashCode` calculation as well to break the cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to print the model class which has join. so while fetching the table data you want, the other tables joined are also fetched. That's causing the stack-overflow error. You can use DTO classes to print the attributes.

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class ShoppingCartDTO {
     private Long id;
     Client client;
     Set<CartItem> items;
     public ShoppingCartDTO(ShoppingCart shoppingCart)
    {
       //setters here
     }
}
```

create DTO for the cartItem also.

Comment: How i do that ?

Comment: I have updated the answer.